# Firefox SDK simple storage loses associative array data after restart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

### About

I'm working on an add-on with the Firefox SDK. In the addon I store an associative array with simple-storage.

### Code

Associative array I store with simple prefs

```
var spammer = [];
spammer['id'] = res[0];
spammer['username'] = res[1];
spammer['date'] = res[2];

ss.storage.spammers.push(spammer);

console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['id']);
console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['username']);
console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['date']);
```

This seems to work, while the add-on is active the right values are logged.

[image: screenshot1]

However when I the browser the following code is run

```
require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", function(tab) {
    for (i = 0; i < ss.storage.spammers.length; i++) {
        console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['id']);
        console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['username']);
        console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['date']);
    }
});
```

But now when I run the code is run 'undefined' values are logged

[image: screenshot2]

(the first 3 lines are from previous session stored with simple-prefs, the 3 working lines are from the new session)

- the correct number of logs are made, so the correct number of values are present
- I use the SDK profiles correctly

### Question

Is it not possible to store associative arrays with simple-storage or is something else the matter?

Comment: Does this happen with 'cfx run' or also when you install your add on?

Comment: This happens when I run 'cfx run' with the --profiledir option. Old stored data returns as undefined. All data added from current session is returned OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
var spammer = [];
spammer['id'] = res[0];
spammer['username'] = res[1];
spammer['date'] = res[2];

ss.storage.spammers.push(spammer);

console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['id']);
console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['username']);
console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i]['date']);
```

Change `var spammer = [];` to `var spammer = {};`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution [by erikvold]

My current running code:

```
if (!ss.storage.spammers)
{
    ss.storage.spammers = [];
}

var spammer = {};
spammer.userid = res[0];
spammer.username = res[1];
spammer.date = res[2];

ss.storage.spammers.push(spammer);

console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i].userid);
console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i].username);
console.log(ss.storage.spammers[i].date);
```